# Scalable/Responsible Polling of 3rd-Party API

Tags: architecture, scalability, polling

I maintain an application which acts as a wrapper for a social media site which exposes an API. My application tracks specific posts made by each user and reports on the latest activity on each post.

I am currently working on a refactor of the application and would like to add real-time update functionality (i.e. if the user leaves the page open, it will update with new changes to the tracked posts when applicable). However, I am not sure of the best practices for doing something like this.

Something like SignalR or other websocket framework would be great as far as getting the data from my backend to my frontend code, but the 3rd-party API just exposes a bunch of REST endpoints. My backend, presumably, would be therefore polling the 3rd-party API for the data for each individual post at some regular interval.

No matter how I think about trying to implement this, though, it seems pretty unscalable as my number of users (and therefore number of tracked posts) grows, especially as regards my usage of the third-party's resources. (I already occasionally have to throttle my requests when the user loads the app in the first place.)

Is there a best practice scalable/responsible way to retrieve such remote static data in a way that balances resource usage and user experience?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what stack you prefer to use, so I will have to answer this generically.

If the system you are intending to integrate with only supports a REST interface, polling is indeed what you will need to do. To make it scalable however, I would segregate the retrieval of data from the process providing real-time updates. The two main components are then:

- Poll the REST web-service and update your datastore
- Use a real-time engine for sending data from your datastore

The nature of the data you are retrieving, what you need / intend to do with the data, and what your target platforms are, would all drive decisions for what an appropriate stack would be. The solution retrieving the data could be completely different than what you design to send the data from your datastore, as well.